# Blank 404 error page while using Twig template and Timber (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I am using [Timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/) for a WordPress project. I am trying to get my custom 404 error page twig template to display on 404 errors. Currently, my 404 errors are showing a blank screen. However, when I go to the route: `/404` my template displays. I am assuming there is either something wrong with how I am routing or I am missing some key logic in `404.php`.

How can I get my twig template to display for my 404 errors?

Route code in `functions.php`:

```
Routes::map('/404', function($params){
Routes::load('routes/404.php', null, $params, 404);
});
```

`404.php`:

```
<?php
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['page'] = $post;

global $wp;
$url = home_url($wp->request);
$context['url'] = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', rtrim($url, '/'));

$context['global'] = get_fields('options');

Timber::render('views/pages/404.twig', $context);
```

`404.twig`:

```
{% extends "layouts/layout.twig" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row row-is-centered">
<div class="col ns-col-is-8 lead-6 txt-center">
<h1 class="txt-size-5">Our apologies, we couldn't find {{url}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Check where your **404.php** is placed. If it’s not in the root folder of your theme, it might not work. Also, check out @robertguss’s answer. He has some good guidance on the routing thing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to setup any custom routing in order for WordPress to pick up the 404 page. Here is the [WP Codex on 404 Pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)

Also if you are using the Timber starter theme, this works out of the box by default. Here are the files that come with the theme, I just tested this on a Timber project I am currently working on and I haven't done anything to setup a custom 404 page. I just have what the Timber starter theme comes with by default:

#### 404.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found)
 *
 * Methods for TimberHelper can be found in the /functions sub-directory
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since    Timber 0.1
 */

$context = Timber::get_context();
Timber::render( '404.twig', $context );
```

#### 404.twig

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    Sorry, we couldn't find what you're looking for.
{% endblock %}
```

It also looks like routes are now deprecated: https://timber.github.io/docs/upgrade-guides/1.0/#routes

I am not sure how far along you are in your project, but you might want to try to upgrade to the latest version of Timber and use their starter theme to get going. They provide a lot of templates that work out of the box and make things a lot easier. However, you should be careful upgrading if you are pretty far along in your project because I am sure there will be breaking changes like the routes feature for instance. The page referenced above provides some good information on whether or not you should upgrade and how to do so.

Hope that helps.